# How to join table with django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Assumes, I have two tables below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBnOK.png)

I've made the models.py:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    Student_Id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    Grade = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status= models.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        db_table ='T_Score'


class Student(models.Model):
    Student_Id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    Student_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Student_Class = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.Student_Id,
            "name" : self.Student_Name,
        }

    class Meta:
        db_table ='T_Student'
```

Is it possible to join the table if Student.Student_Id just as primary key (not as foreign too)? And how should I make the view.py and template which represent Student ID, Student Name, and Grade?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really experience with Django,  but as far as joining the two tables is concerned, you can. Joining two tables that have primary and foreign key relationships is actually the same as putting ordinary RESTRICT operation on the row,   i.e by explicitly use. WHERE Students.students_id = Score.students_id. Ordinary Join automatically figures that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you update your models.py.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)

class Score(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status= models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

You can access the Score model in the views.py

```
scores = Score.objects.all()
context = {
    'scores': scores
}
```

Accessing scores in the HTML template

```
{% for score in scores %}
    ID - {{ score.student.id }}
    NAME - {{ score.student.name }}
    GRADE - {{ score.grade }}
{% endfor %}
```